# Text under text under symbol in an equation

Tags: equations

I need something like this where there's another line of text stacked under text under symbol.

[image]

I tried this:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sigg}{\Sigma}    
(...)
$\sigg\limits_{x\in X} \sigg\limits_{w\in W} w=\sigg\limits_{w\in \sigg_{X\in X}x}w,$
```

but \limits stops working and writes the "X in X" in the subscript instead of writing below.

[image]

Does someone know a way to this?

Comment: `\substack{foo\\ faa}` is what you need. `\sum_{\substack{i=1\\3<4}}`

Comment: Unrelated: Note that in inline math (aka within `$...$`) you should not use `\limits` as it will severely disturb the line spacing.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `\Sigma` rather than `\sum`, other than that the model used what is apparently an italicized Sigma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve by introducing one more `\limits` tag,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\sigg}{\Sigma}    

\begin{document}

\[
\sigg\limits_{x\in X} \sigg\limits_{w\in W} w=\sigg\limits_{w\in
\sigg\limits_{X\in X}x}w,
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: `\sigma` is not  `\sum` ...

Comment: @Zarko I thought the same, but the `OP` given `\Sigma`, so I just followed the `OP's` tags... Shall I change it?

Comment: @MadyYuvi, this is up to you :-). At least warn OP, that `sigma` is letter, and `sum` is operator. And that is advisable to use standard notation and syntax in writing of math. I add such note to my answer.

Comment: That sigma in the limits, weirdly spaced to accommodate the $X\in X$ under it, doesn't look great...

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{x\in X} \sum_{w\in W} w = \sum_{w\in\sum\limits_{\mathclap{x\in X}}X} w
\]

\end{document}
```

Note: don't mix letters and math operators: `\Sigma` is letter, `\sum` is operator.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant after two nice answers. I use (see the first comment of @Sigur) often `\substack` command. And I have added two times `\mathclap` because I have decrease the blank space between the `\sum` and `w`. Here there is a screenshot of my result.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{x\in X} \sum_{w\in W} w = 
\sum_{\mathclap{\substack{w\in\!\sum\limits_{x\in X}\mathclap{X}}}} w
\]
\end{document}
```